# Caliburn NotifyOfPropertyChanged : System.InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

We are using caliburn framework in our application.

I have a property in my view model which should invoke a `NotifyOfPropertyChanged` for another property when it's value changes.

I thought I'd be able to do that as follows:

```
    public AnalogSensorState State
    {
        get
        {
            if (LowerErrorLevelExceeded)
            {
                return AnalogSensorState.LowerErrorExceeded;
            }
            if (LowerWarningLevelExceeded)
            {
                return AnalogSensorState.LowerWarningExceeded;
            }
            if (UpperErrorLevelExceeded)
            {
                return AnalogSensorState.UpperErrorExceeded;
            }
            if (UpperWarningLevelExceeded)
            {
                return AnalogSensorState.UpperWarningExceeded;
            }
            return AnalogSensorState.Ok;
        }
    }

    public bool LowerErrorLevelExceeded
    {
        get => _lowerErrorLevelExceeded;
        set
        {
            Set(ref _lowerErrorLevelExceeded, value, nameof(LowerErrorLevelExceeded));
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => nameof(State));
        }
    }
    ...
```

When the boolean setter is executed I get an invalid cast exception on the `NotifyOfPropertyChange` call.

Why?

Exception:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression' to type
>   'System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression'.'

Comment: You wanted to write `NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => State);`

Comment: `nameof(State)` is a compile time constant (equivalent to the literal `"State"`). I don't know that `NotifyOfPropertyChange()` method, but it seems to expect a _member expression_, so possibly `() => this.State`.

Comment: Hmm, that's surprising, the interface is defined as `public virtual bool Set<T>(ref T oldValue, T newValue, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)`

Comment: Argh... wake up already.... Sorry I am mixing things up...

Comment: try to use just `NotifyOfPropertyChange(nameof(State));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use either `NotifyOfPropertyChange(nameof(State));` or `NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => State);`, according to [`PropertyChangedBase`](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/blob/master/src/Caliburn.Micro.Core/PropertyChangedBase.cs) class in `Caliburn.Micro`. It accepts string with property name or `Expression<Func<TProperty>>` for property

```cs
    /// <summary>Notifies subscribers of the property change.</summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">Name of the property.</param>
    public virtual void NotifyOfPropertyChange([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
      if (!this.IsNotifying || this.PropertyChanged == null)
        return;
      this.OnUIThread((Action) (() => this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))));
    }

    public void NotifyOfPropertyChange<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TProperty>> property)
    {
      this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(property.GetMemberInfo().Name);
    }
```